# RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager: making one cell bigger

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a layout like the image below! the only thing i want is to make the first cell bigger than the others.
what I've tried so far is the below code :

```
        final AdapterFirstPage mAdapter = new AdapterFirstPage(mItems);
    mRecycle.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    final GridLayoutManager mng_layout = new GridLayoutManager(this, 6);
    mng_layout.setSpanSizeLookup( new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            int index = position%2 ;
            switch(index){
               case 0: return 4;
               case 1: return 2;
               case 2: return 2;
               case 3: return 3;
               case 4: return 3;
               default: return -1;
            }

        }
    });
        mRecycle.setLayoutManager(mng_layout);
```

actually i've played around with spanCount and changed it from 6 to 4 and still I'm not close to the image below!
can anyone please help me to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may do this programmatically as follows:

```
private GridLayout setUpGrid(List<PictureUrlWithStatus> picWithStatusList) {

    if (picWithStatusList == null) { // No Photos present i.e. no Photos are added
        return null;
    }

    GridLayout.LayoutParams gridLayoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    gridLayoutParams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    gridLayoutParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
    gridLayout.setLayoutParams(gridLayoutParams);
    gridLayout.removeAllViews();

    int total_gridCount = picWithStatusList.size();
    int column = 3;
    int rowSize = total_gridCount / column;
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(column);

    //(For First Image which occupies 2 rows), If you are drawing less than 3 images, use 2 rows, else setRowCount as the default (rowSize + 1), extra as the first Image occupies 2 rows and still draws only 3 images.
    if (rowSize == 0)
        gridLayout.setRowCount(2);
    else
        gridLayout.setRowCount(rowSize + 1);

    for (int c = 0;/*getcount from  picWithStatusList*/; c++) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageLayoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        //The ImageView to load image
        ImageView profilePic = new ImageView(this);
        profilePic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        profilePic.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        profilePic.setLayoutParams(imageLayoutParam);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams picstatusLayoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        picstatusLayoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        //The View for Text written Below Image
        TextView profilePicStatus = new TextView(this);
        profilePicStatus.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
        profilePicStatus.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        profilePicStatus.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 0);
        profilePicStatus.setLayoutParams(picstatusLayoutParam);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams contentLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        contentLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        RelativeLayout contentLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        contentLayout.addView(profilePic);
        contentLayout.addView(profilePicStatus);
        contentLayout.setLayoutParams(contentLayoutParams);

        if (c >= 0) {
            if (c == 0) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        2 * width / 3, 2 * width / 3);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                        layoutParams);
                param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(c, 2);
                param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, 2);

                //Load image into profilePic (ImageView), I am assuming you have imageurl in profilePicWithStatus

                //The text written on top of the images.
                profilePicStatus.setText(c + " ");
                contentLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
            } else {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        1 * width / 3, 1 * width / 3);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                        layoutParams);
                param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                //Load image into profilePic (ImageView), I am assuming you have imageurl in profilePicWithStatus

                //The Text to be written on the top of image with align bottom
                profilePicStatus.setText(c + " ");
                contentLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
            }

        }
        gridLayout.addView(contentLayout);
    }
    return gridLayout;
}
```

Also,

PictureUrlWithStatus is a class as follows:

```
private class PictureUrlWithStatus {
    // url is the Picture url and status will be 'Y'/'y' or 'N'/'n'
    String url, status;

    public PictureUrlWithStatus(String pictureUrl, String pictureStatus) {
        this.url = pictureUrl;
        this.status = pictureStatus;
    }
}
```

This should set you up

Comment: Roadblock can you show me more? from layout to code?! i need more code from you , can't understand this!

Comment: You need to create layouts programmatically. What I did was check that if I am creating first image, then it should occupy 2/3 of width and 2/3 of height (occupying space equivalent to 2 rows and 2 columns in terms of grid). This gets compensated against the 2 images drawn one in each rows. For rest of the cases, you need to draw as 1/3 of width and 1/3 of height. and such conditions follow....

Comment: The content Layout contains the each grid items and the image view is added with LinearLayout.Layoutparams. Once you prepare it as per the size of the layout, you add that layout to your original gridLayout

Comment: can you tell me what is picWithStatusList and here gridLayout.setColumnCount(column); what is gridLayout exactly?! what you put on xml layout? and also what is contentLayout here

Comment: I have updated my Code. Included  more details and also, more code as per the need. The function should return you the grid you are looking for. I have added comments too. I am assuming that the text in urdu below is a textView and pictureStatus is that string. Edit as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

That is a limitation of `GridLayoutManager`.  For a vertical scroll, items can only extend across columns and vice versa.  It makes the layout calculations a lot simpler when you can't extend across both rows and columns.

If you are trying to do something really simple as in your illustration -- only spanning both rows and columns on the very first image -- then what I would suggest is rethinking this so your first three images are on one row. Your second and third images to the right of the large image would actually be part of the same list item.

- Change your adapter to have a special item that represents the second position; for instance, a list of items that includes the second and third item.
- Change your adapter to ignore the third item completely.  So for adapter position 2 (zero-based) which would normally return the third item, return the fourth item, and so forth.  The missing third item has been represented in the list with the second item.
- Give that special item (the list) a different view type.  Create a view that stacks two images vertically.  Binding would then involve the second and third item from that list.

Your span count is clearly 3 since you have three columns.  The first item has a span size of 2, the second/third combo item has a span size of 1.

Tweak up the margins on your dual view to match the margins from the `RecyclerView` and you're in business.

Comment: I know this question is old; I just ran across it and had the idea, so I thought I'd post it just in case it helps anyone else.  If you're interested in seeing code, reply to this comment and I can update the answer.

Comment: Hi, Kris larson i am interested for the same

Answer (score 0):

Your shouldn't use GridLayoutManager if you want achieve different size items.You should implement your own LayoutManager like [this](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view).